# want to play audio file which is AES encrypted and the file format is .ism/manifest

Tags: android, xamarin, native

We are developing the App for Android, iOS and Windows Phone using Xamarin Native. We want to play audio file which is AES encrypted and the file format is .ism/manifest. We are looking for the solution to play encrypted audio using Xamarin native.

Please provide solution/ sample code to play the audio using .ism files.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.